# Save Christmas by calculating how many 2 m and 5 m wire lengths can go in a certain total length of Christmas lights installation

Tags: calculus, functions, logic, optimization, linear-programming

I have a type of interconnectable, linear Christmas lights installation. Two types of lengths of
wire can be added to the line.

- Wire type A is 2 meters, with 20 LEDs lights
- Wire type B is 5 meters, with 50 LEDs lights

The total number of lights cannot go over 5500 LEDs for any combinations and number of wires.

- A 2 meters long light installation can use one two meters wire, for
  20 LEDs
- A 7 meters light installation can use one two meters wire
  and one 5 meters wire, for 70 LEDs
- A 21 meters light installation can
  use 3 two meters wires and three 5 meters wires, for 210 LEDs
- A 58
  meters light installation can use 9 two meters wires and 8 5 meters
  wires, for 580 LEDs

What math formula can I use to calculate the possible combinations? There are hundreds of possible possible total lengths and it would be great to do this on Excel or with Javascript.

Also, if possible, how to change the math formula for when I want to use wire type A more than wire type B, or the other way around?

Thank you!

Comment: I like your "save Christmas" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_{A}$ and $x_{B}$ be the number of type A and B wires you will use, respectively. Following inequality must hold so as not to exceed 5500 LED limit:

$20x_{A}+50x_{B} \leq 5500$

and $x_{A}, x_{B}$ are non-negative integers. You can enumerate all feasible choices as follows:

If you were to choose only type A, you can use up to 275 wires. So $x_{A}$ can be $0,1,...,275$. Let's say you have chosen $x^{*}_{A}$ many type A wires. The maximum value for $x^{*}_{B}$ would be $x_{B} = floor(\frac{5500-20x^{*}_{A}}{50})$. So given $x^{*}_{A}$, you can choose $x^{*}_{B}$ as $0,...,floor(\frac{5500-20x^{*}_{A}}{50})$. The total wire length would be $2x^{*}_{A}+5x^{*}_{B}$.

Example: Let $x^{*}_{A} = 98$, then $x^{*}_{B}$ can be $0,1,2,..,floor(70.4)=70$.

So you can start with $x^{*}_{A}=0$, calculate and list all possible $x^{*}_{B}$, then increase $x^{*}_{A}$ until 275. "sequence" command in Excel can be useful for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this, cbs! Have a great day :)